# How many 7 permutations of $\{1,\ldots,9\}$ are there such that $5$ and $6$ do not appear consecutively

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, permutations

I found this problem in the textbook *Introductory Combinatorics*, and am very confused by the answer provided by the text. Here is how I tried to solve it:

Define $P_{r,n}$ to be $r$-permutations of a set with $n$ elements.

Then there are, in total, $P_{9,7}$ $7$-permutations of our set. Considering the subset of permutations where $[5,6]$ occurs, in that order, there are $P_{8,7}$ such permutations, since we can treat $[5,6]$ as one element. Similarly for $[6,5]$.

Thus the solution must be $P_{9,7} - 2*P_{8,7} = 100800$. But the textbook instead breaks it down into 4 cases: (i) neither $5,6$ appear, (ii) both $5,6$ appear, $iii, iv$ one of the two appears. They find the answer $186,480$.

What is wrong with my reasoning that I got the solution wrong?

Comment: @trueblueanil aren't they cover by $P_{9,7}$? Since this gives the total permutations of the $9$ elements into list of $7$, including the $5,6$ cases.

Comment: If $56$ is made into a single block which you choose,  then you only need to choose $5$ others to get $7$ characters.

Comment: @lulu So I am choosing 5 out of 8, not 7 out of 8? How's that? Also that still doesn't give my textbook's answer. That answer seems a bit out of place; it's greater than $P_{9,7}$ which I'm not sure how that's possible.

Comment: You are trying to remove the "bad" strings, right?  Well, let's count the bad strings that contain $56$ as a block.  You need to choose fine numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,7,8,9\}$ and there are $\binom 75=21$ ways to do that.  Then you have $6!$ ways to permute the six objects you have (the five you just chose plus the $56$ block.  Double to cover $65$.

Comment: But...$\binom 97\times 7!=181440$, right? And that's the unrestricted number of choices.  How could the restricted number be greater?

Comment: Your $P_{8,7}$ will count $(1,2,3,4,7,8,9)$ (which should not be eliminated !) & $(1,2,3,4,56,8,9)$ (which has 8 Digits !) : Hence , it will over-count. Hence you are getting less than the Correct Answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that what with your approach and the book's answer, there is confusion worse confounded. I don't see how cases can be avoided, so let's see case by case, calling numbers other than $5,6$ as "ordinary" and $5,6$ as "special"

- $7$ ordinary: $7!$
- $6$ ordinary and $1$ special: $\binom76\binom21 7!$
- $5$ ordinary, $2$ special: $\binom75(7!-2*6!)$
- Add up to get a total of $151200$

Comment: While this gives me the answer -- which, btw, the book must've gotten wrong -- I am confused as to where my answer goes wrong. Where, exactly, is the logical error I am making?

Comment: The logical error you are making is computing [All$7-$permutations] $-$[ Permutations where $5,6$ are not together, **assuming that $5,6$ are necessarily in the $7-$permutation]**

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong when counting the number of permutations containing $[5,6]$, and the same mistake for $[6,5]$. You should count the number of permutations that contain both $5$ and $6$, where $5$ and $6$ are consecutive.

Hence, you get the right answer when replacing $P(8,7)$ by $C(7,5)*6!$. The right answer is $151200$, I think. The answer in the textbook is also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mathematica to verify your result.

```
allPermutations = Permutations[Range[9], {7}];
consecutive56Permutations = 
  Select[allPermutations, (SequencePosition[#, {5, 6}] =!= {} || 
      SequencePosition[#, {6, 5}] =!= {}) &];
result = Length[allPermutations] - Length[consecutive56Permutations]
```

$$
\color{red}{151200}
$$